# TypeORM cannot use cli with configuration

Tags: node.js, typescript, discord.js, typeorm, typeorm-activerecord

I have my (typescript) Project (Its a discord bot if that is important), which contains a "ormconfig.json" file. This file contains my configuration for TypeORM, see as follows:

```json
{
    "type": "mysql",
    "host": "<IP of my server>",
    "port": 3306,
    "username": "<MySQL User>",
    "password": "<MySQL Password>",
    "database": "<existing MySQL database>",
    "synchronize": true,
    "logging": false,
    "entities": [
        "src/entities/*.ts"
    ],
    "migrations": [
        "src/migration/*.ts"
    ],
    "subscribers": [
        "src/subscriber/*.ts"
    ],
    "cli": {
        "entitiesDir": "src/entities/",
        "migrationsDir": "src/migration/",
        "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber/"
    }
}
```

Now, if I run anything on my actual server, the configuration in general works. Entities get loaded correctly and I can use them as intended. Now I made some changes in an entity, which means I would have to do a migration. Trying to generate the migration made the actual problem appear.

I tried running the following command:

```sh
npm run typeorm migration:show -- -d .\ormconfig.json
```

I expected this to load the config, connect to the server, check the database and give me output. Yet when it loads, it simply throws an error, saying

`Given data source file must contain export of a DataSource instance`

I also tried doing it over javascript, yet when I export a "DataSource"-Instance, i receive a similar error:

`Invalid file path given: "C:\temp\Bot\src\database.ts". File must contain a TypeScript / JavaScript code and export a DataSource instance.`

Following also my package.json file, for the dependencies of the project.

```json
{
  "name": "Bot",
  "version": "1.1.1",
  "description": "desc",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "serve": "npx ts-node src/index.ts",
    "start": "npx ts-node src/index.ts",
    "typeorm": "npx --require ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js",
  },
  "author": "PlayWolfYT",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@discordjs/builders": "^0.12.0",
    "@discordjs/rest": "^0.3.0",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.4",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.8",
    "discord-api-types": "^0.27.0",
    "discord.js": "^13.6.0",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.2",
    "nodemon": "2.0.15",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "ts-node": "^10.5.0",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.3",
    "typescript": "^4.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^17.0.21",
    "@discordjs/builders": "^0.12.0",
    "@discordjs/rest": "^0.3.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

So, you are using one of the newer versions of Typeorm, in which they dropped support to `ormconfig.{json,xml}` file. You'll have to put your database connection options in a `{ts,js}` file using a [Data Source](https://typeorm.io/#/data-source) and export it.

Two options to work with your problem:

- Downgrade your typeorm to `0.2.45`: `npm i typeorm@0.2.45`;
- Update your code following the new docs: [Typeorm docs](https://typeorm.io/#/);

I can help you setup through editing this answer if needed, just comment it below.

Answer (score 5):

Create a file named "data-source.ts"

```
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
  type: 'mysql',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 3306,
  username: 'user',
  password: 'pass',
  database: 'db_name',
  entities: [],
  migrations: [],
  subscribers: [],
});
```

then run

> npm run typeorm migration:show -- -d "path/data-source.ts"

Comment: I tried doing that before. Didnt work out. Tried it again now, even tried doing it without the remote connection and just connecting to the localhost server, yet I always get the same error. See [this pastebin for the error](https://pastebin.com/sJeYZFDa) and [this pastebin for the code](https://pastebin.com/pdbPp476)

Answer (score 2):

```
// ./data-source.ts
import { DataSource } from "typeorm"
import { Table } from "./entity/Table"

export default new DataSource({
    type: "mysql",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 3306,
    username: "user",
    password: "password",
    database: "db",
    synchronize: true,
    logging: false,
    entities: [Table],
    migrations: [],
    subscribers: [],
})
```

> if use mysql piz npm package use `mysql2`

`Typeorm@0.3.x` if use `TypeScript` connection: 
`npx typeorm-ts-node-commonjs schema:sync -d ./data-source.ts`

if play sample: 
`npx typeorm init --database mysql && npm uninstall mysql && npm install mysql2`